# how to use template literal strings for modular css with JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, template-literals

I want to be able to give a different className when mapping through an array of images like so:

```
{array.map((step, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            <img className={styles.img`${i}`} />
          </>
        )
      })}
```

However I keep getting an error on Gatsby:
Error in function eval in ...file path
and then
*filepath_module_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default.img is not a function

What syntax error am I doing here? How can I dynamically change classNames if not like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how your styles look like but maybe that would work:

```
<img className={styles.img[i]} />
```

or

```
<img className={styles[`img${i}`]} />
```