# How to get className to work with dynamic input from map()

Tags: reactjs, jsx, string-literals

Trying to render some buttons dynamically, cant get the styling to work.

I have my btnList -

```
const btnList= [
  "FirsBtn",
  "SecondBtn",
  "ThirdBtn",
  "ForthBtn",
  "FifthBtn",
  "SixthBtn",
];
```

I have my map function -

```
const RenderBtns = (btnList) => {
    return btnList.map((btn) => {
      return (
       <button className={`classes.${btn}`} name={btn} onClick={onClickHandler}>{btn}</button>
      );
    });
  };
```

And, I have my btn.module.css, with

```
.FirstBtn {background-color: #662626;}
.SecondBtn {background-color: #b0bf76;}
.ThirdBtn {background-color: #6b8327;}
.ForthBtn {background-color: #6a5938;}
.FifthBtn {background-color: #b0bf76;}
.SixthBtn {background-color: #1fa593;}
```

The styling, doesn't work.

This - `className={classes.FirstBtn}` works.

This - `` className={`${classes.SecondBtn}`} `` works.

This - `` className={`${classes}.${btn}`} `` Doesn't.

The buttons themselves, the clicks, everything else - works.

I went through all of the combinations, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Even though I get the main idea behind literal, and object,

at this point I'm just beat-up.

I want to get the className to accept the dynamic "btn"

any way to make it happen?

Help, Please, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Almost gave up on google, and than I stumbled upon this
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68909404/10295425)

It was actually the second one that worked for me,

 but n one the less - it worked.

```
className={classes[`${item}Btn`]}
```